# check a string inside a string in a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
list = [america , china, japan, mvnsangameshertet,]
```

I want to check whether the any string in the list contains the name `sangamesh`. for example:

I can use this:

```
for a in list:
    if "sangamesh" in a:
        print True
    else:
        print False
```

But this gives me result like

```
False
False
False
True
```

I just want the output as either `True` or `False`

I am still a beginner I tried a lot but couldnt come up with an alternative!

Comment: You really do not want to not name a variable `list`; that variable now masks the built-in type.

Comment: @yardsale8 - Please do not change code within a question, because it may obscure the problem that brought them here in the first place or prevent others from providing an answer. If you spot a problem with the code, please post an answer or leave a comment.

Comment: @Leigh    agree..makes sense!!

Comment: @MartijnPieters i just used it to represent it as a list .. i understand it is against the coding standards.Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`any()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
print any("sangamesh" in a for a in lst)
```

This will return `True` as soon as there is any `a` for which the test is `True`; it won't test any more values after that.

For future reference, you could also end your loop with `break`:

```
for a in lst:
    if "sangamesh" in a:
        print True
        break
else:
    print False
```

Note that the `else` is now part of the *`for` loop* instead; if you do not break out of the loop, at the end the `else` suite is executed, but if you *do* `break`, then the `else` suite is skipped.

Comment: @martijin pieters perfect!!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> items = ["america" , "china", "japan", "mvnsangameshertet"]
>>> any("sangamesh" in s for s in items)
True
```

Comment: @leigh y did u rollback..i think the string has to be in quotes..the suggestion was right! :O